# Issue with checking if ID in class has changed

Tags: c#, csv

I have a class called `Line` that stores bunch of information including the ID of the Line(I have a list of lines). I am writing this information in a CSV file and I want to check if the first character of my ID has changed (hopefully to a greater number). This change signifies a new folder.
Here is what I have tried:

```
public bool IsNewFile (Line ln)
    {
        int newID = ln.getID()[0];
        int oldID = 0;
        if (newID != oldID)
        {
            oldID = newID;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            oldID = newID;
            return false;

        }

    }
```

Here is my store to csv method:

```
 public void csvWriter (Line ln, StreamWriter stream)//Writes List to CSV
    {
        //some code here
        if (IsNewFile(ln))
        {
           //MAGICAL LINE
        }
        else
        {
           //NOT MAGICAL LINE
        }

        stream.WriteLine(printLine);
    }
```

here is getID()

```
public string getID()
    {
        return id;
    }
```

With the current code I print MAGICAL LINE every time! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What should getID() return? A list of characters?

Comment: I think you should post the code of `ln.getID()[0]` - because it seems the return code of that expression ALWAYS is different to 0. As a consequence, you always land in the first part of the `if` statement.

Comment: Hmm.. you basically do the same in `if` and `else` : `oldID = newID;`

Comment: The value of oldID i reset always to 0 int oldID = 0; any ID different of 0 it will be true . You have to store oldID as class variable.

Comment: OMG I just saw it...

Comment: @voytek No, the function `IsNewFile()` always returns true, and that's because `newId != oldId` is alwas true, and that again is because `ln.getID()[0]` is alwas not 0 ...

Comment: Thanks everybody, I am sorry for wasting your time with such dumb mistake......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're always checking if the newID is != 0 because you always initialize oldID to 0. You should store the oldID in your Line class because as of now, setting oldID = newID will do nothing as those variables will get destroyed when the function returns its boolean.

```
public bool IsNewFile (Line ln)
{
    int newID = ln.getID()[0];
    int oldID = ln.getOldID()[0];
    if (newID != oldID)
    {
        ln.oldID = newID;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        ln.oldID = newID;
        return false;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you are giving us enough information but oldID is always 0. You need to store oldID and compare it to newID somewhere.